# window.prompt can't translate Resource

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
var Password= prompt("@Resource.EnterPassword" + UserID);
```

on debug mode, I can translate to other language, but when I release to IIS manager, it still prompt english, is there any setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable for resource get from C#

```
<script> 
var resource = '@Resource.EnterPassword' 
var Password= prompt(resource + UserID);
</script>
```

Comment: Tried, but still can't, I also tried add input hidden value in html, and use document.getElementById to get value, but it get [object HTMLDivElement], is that can't working?

Comment: <div type="hidden" id="EnterPassword" name="EnterPassword" value="@Resource.EnterPassword"></div>

<script>
var resource = document.getElementById('EnterPassword');
</script>

Comment: you can use hidden field to archive this

Comment: still get English, but other content's language is changed, so difficult

Comment: Can you post your controller here?

Comment: No need, problem solved, I just reimport all source code to IIS, and then works by you method, thanks